Getting ProducerFencedException during producer.send in Springboot application during Kafka Split-brain test
We have a Spring Boot application deployed on DC1 that connects to a Kafka cluster with its leader in DC2. There was a 9-second connection outage for Kafka on DC1, during which the application was unable to produce messages using the Spring Kafka transactional producer. After 9 seconds, the Kafka connection was restored, and a new leader election took place. However, the Spring Kafka transactional producer still couldn’t publish messages and encountered a ProducerFencedException. It took around 60 minutes for application to recover.
My concern is that since Spring Kafka uses a cached producer, it may not have refreshed the metadata to reconnect properly, resulting in the exception due to an expired epoch on the server side.
How can I configure my Spring Kafka producer to handle this situation effectively
we cannot make producer non transactional and idempotency is required in our usecases.

Interesting issue. Let's see if we can come up with some recommendations. How do you notice that the app is recovering after 60 minutes? I am curious what caused the metadata to refresh correctly after an hour?
